# Inheriting generic typealias with `where` clause

Tags: swift, generics

Here's a reduction of what I'm observing:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> {} // yes

typealias MyType<T> = MyGenericClass<T> where T: UIView // yes

class MyOtherClass<T>: MyType<T> {} // nope
```

What I was hoping — i.e. the whole reason I defined the typealias — was that I might be able to avoid repeating the `where` clause, which in real life is huge. Is that just impossible?